# im tring to debug a program with gdb but im not able to remove optimizations

Tags: c, makefile, gdb

```
make CFLAGS+="-g -O0 -fsanitize=address"
```

after running that, I still have this on the backtrace -

```
 0x000000000040146e in main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>)
```

Make file code block

```
 # Add -Werror if defined
    CFLAGS = -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers 
    CFLAG_CARES_SYMBOL_HIDING = -fvisibility=hidden
    CPP = `enter code here`gcc -E
    CPPFLAGS = 
    CPPFLAG_CARES_STATICLIB = 
    CYGPATH_W = echo
    DEFS = -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
```

Comment: Did you run `make clean` first?

Comment: Not every optimization can be prevented. Even with minimal optimization level the compiler might do some basic clean-up

Comment: yes, i run the make clean every time. I tried them with the -rdynamic now, but it didn't help as well

Comment: If your compiler supports it, you might want to use `-Og` instead of `-O0` to optimize for debugging.

Comment: no luck with Og either...

Comment: Please edit your question and post your `Makefile` in a code block and a code block that has the output of the make command. Your makefile probably has a line like: `CFLAGS += -O2` in it. The compiler will use the _last_ `-O` option it sees so your make args won't override the makefile as you've written things.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as I said in my top comments, your `Makefile` is overriding your command line arguments.

Rather than have the `make` arguments do things, let's have the `Makefile` do the heavy lifting.

Here is a refactored `Makefile`:

```
# Add -Werror if defined
CFLAGS += -Wno-system-headers

# compile for debug
ifdef DEBUG
  CFLAGS += -g
  CFLAGS += -fsanitize=address
# compile for production
else
  CFLAGS += -O2
endif

CFLAG_CARES_SYMBOL_HIDING = -fvisibility=hidden
CPP = gcc -E
CPPFLAGS =
CPPFLAG_CARES_STATICLIB =
CYGPATH_W = echo
DEFS = -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
```

To build for release, just do:

```
make
```

To build for debug, do:

```
make DEBUG=1
```

---

We can be a bit more sophisticated. When we want debugging, we don't *always* want `-fsanitize=address`.

So, we can make separate options:

```
# Add -Werror if defined
CFLAGS += -Wno-system-headers

# compile for debug
ifdef DEBUG
  CFLAGS += -g
# compile for production
else
  CFLAGS += -O2
endif

ifdef FSANITIZE
  CFLAGS += -fsanitize=address -O0 -g
endif

CFLAG_CARES_SYMBOL_HIDING = -fvisibility=hidden
CPP = gcc -E
CPPFLAGS =
CPPFLAG_CARES_STATICLIB =
CYGPATH_W = echo
DEFS = -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
```

Then, we can do either:

```
make DEBUG=1
```

Or:

```
make DEBUG=1 FSANITIZE=1
```

Even if we forget to add `DEBUG=1` when we do `FSANITIZE=1`, we'll get a `CFLAGS` result of:

```
-O2 -fsanitize=address -g -O0
```

Because `-O0` appears *last*, it will override `-O2`

These are just some simple examples. Create the `Makefile` with as many options as you want.

Comment: I don't think the claim that the makefile is overriding the command line is completely accurate.  I don't believe that `+=` is supported command line syntax, so `CFLAGS` is never really getting set from the command line at all.  If the command line used `CFLAGS="..."` instead, then the command line would override the `CFLAGS=...` within the Makefile as expected, see https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Overriding.html#Overriding for details on this.

Comment: When a `make` variable actually is set via command-line argument, that overrides any assignments in the makefile, not the other way around.  In turn, assignments in the makefile override values read from the environment.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is with the command line notation:

```
make CFLAGS+="-g -O0 -fsanitize=address"
```

does not do what you think it does.  I don't actually know what this does.

What you should write is (note the missing `+`):

```
make CFLAGS="-g -O0 -fsanitize=address"
```

Passing VARIABLE=VALUE on the make command line will override any VARIABLE=VALUE within the makefile.  The documentation for this can be [found here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Overriding.html#Overriding).

Here's an example of it in action:

```
$ cat Makefile
CFLAGS = -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers 

all:
    @echo "CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS)"
$ make
CFLAGS = -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers 
$ make CFLAGS="-g0 -O0"
CFLAGS = -g0 -O0
```

You probably spotted the problem here, the `-Wno-system-headers` flag was lost.  You probably wanted that maintained I suspect.

To solve this you will need to tweak your Makefile, here's an improved example:

```
$ cat Makefile
INTERNAL_CFLAGS = -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers $(CFLAGS)

all:
    @echo "CFLAGS = $(INTERNAL_CFLAGS)"
$ make
CFLAGS = -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers 
$ make CFLAGS="-g3 -O0"
CFLAGS = -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -g3 -O0
```

You might worry in the last line about having `-g0` and `-g3` or `-O2` and `-O0`, but most modern compilers will correctly select the last flag in this case, so you'll get the behaviour you want, and this allows you to override only some of the flags from the command line, if that's what you want, e.g. `make CFLAGS="-g3"`, in which case you'll still compile at `-O2`.

However, if the duplicate flags really bothers you, try this one, which I don't recommend:

```
$ cat Makefile
CFLAGS = -g0 -O2
INTERNAL_CFLAGS = -Wno-system-headers $(CFLAGS)

all:
    @echo "CFLAGS = $(INTERNAL_CFLAGS)"
$ make
CFLAGS = -Wno-system-headers -g0 -O2
$ make CFLAGS="-g3 -O0"
CFLAGS = -Wno-system-headers -g3 -O0
```

Here the `-Wno-system-headers` flag will always be retained, but any override of `CFLAGS` on the command line will replace all the `CFLAGS`.